# Displaying unicode characters in Python 3

Tags: python, list, unicode

I have issues with displaying Unicode characters.
As an output I have this list (only on online IDEs):

```
[u'\u0413', u'\0434', u'\043b']
```

How can I convert this sequence to normally visible text?
I have 
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` 
in header and also each string marked as Unicode like u'String'

I tried to use code:
`myList = repr([x.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for x in lst]).decode('string-escape')` but it's not working and output still the same.

Comment: That's not Python 3, that's Python 2.

Comment: Python3 is auto utf8. Better check the version again!

Comment: In Python 2, the representation of unicode values sticks to ASCII-safe characters only. Print individual values instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, this will work directly:

```
>>> [u'\u0413', u'\0434', u'\043b']
['Г', '#4', '#b']
```

In Python 2, you can use the print statement to print individual values:

```
>>> for val in [u'\u0413', u'\0434', u'\043b']:
...   print val
... 
Г
#4
#b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Unfortunately, I was using Python 2 on online IDE, but I thought it was Python 3. Now I'm realised the difference.